# How's the header and body of a http post request?

Tags: http, url, post

Suppose I have `first=John` and `last=Doe` and the following URL: `http://<myurl>/<my controller>`

How would the HTTP message (headers and body) look like for a client receiving a HTTP Post?

Comment: With which encoding? Also, why are you asking? Do you have a specific problem? With specific code?

Comment: @JohnSaunders UTF-8; I'm asking because I'm curious; I don't have a problem; No specific code

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mimic an HTML form submission in a POST request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417224/how-to-mimic-an-html-form-submission-in-a-post-request)

Comment: Easiest way I can think of to see this would be to build a simple form and execute it in the browser, while watching using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/). You can view the raw request and response.

Answer (score 1):

Something like below. You can use firebug browser plug-in to inspect the raw HTTP communication. You can also [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/http-headers-for-dummies/) for more details.

```
POST /mycontroller HTTP/1.1  
Host: localhost  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)  
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8  
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5  
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate  
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7  
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded  
Content-Length: 20  

first=John&last=Doe
```